# group an array on the basis of same value

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by

My array is something like this:

```
myArray = [
  {SKU: "Hoo12", Name: "ACyrlic watch",OrderNo:"26423764233456"},
  {SKU: "S0002", Name: "Princes Geometry",OrderNo:"124963805662313"},
  {SKU: "Hoo12", Name: "ACyrlic watch",OrderNo:"122324234234"},
]


I want to convert

OutPut = [
  {SKU: "Hoo12",Name: "ACyrlic watch", OrderNo: ["26423764233456", "122324234234"]}
  {SKU: "S0002", Name: "Princes Geometry", OrderNo: ["124963805662313"]}
]
```

I want try many methods but I just don't know how to handle the grouping of similar group values.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried?.

Comment: why is c# and jquery in the tags? i dont think those are relevant to the question

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I think jQuery is tagged because he might have tried that, but I agree with C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see data that's grouping  Array.reduce is a good candidate.

eg.

```js
const myArray = [
  {SKU: "Hoo12", Name: "ACyrlic watch",OrderNo:"26423764233456"},
  {SKU: "S0002", Name: "Princes Geometry",OrderNo:"124963805662313"},
  {SKU: "Hoo12", Name: "ACyrlic watch",OrderNo:"122324234234"},
];

const OutPut = myArray.reduce((a,v) => {
  let c = a.find(f => f.SKU === v.SKU);
  //do we have this SKU..
  if (!c) {
    //No lets add
    c = v;
    c.OrderNo = [v.OrderNo];
    a.push(c);
  } else {
    //Yes, lets add this OrderNo.
    c.OrderNo.push(v.OrderNo);
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(OutPut);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `reduce` method, you can achieve your expected output

```js
const myArray = [ {SKU: "Hoo12", Name: "ACyrlic watch",OrderNo:"26423764233456"}, {SKU: "S0002", Name: "Princes Geometry",OrderNo:"124963805662313"}, {SKU: "Hoo12", Name: "ACyrlic watch",OrderNo:"122324234234"}];

const result = Object.values(myArray.reduce((a,{OrderNo, ...r})=>{
    a[r.SKU] ??= {...r, OrderNo:[]};
    a[r.SKU].OrderNo.push(OrderNo)
    return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what is `??=` ?

Comment: @Frenchy  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment

Answer (score 0):

A simple `forEach` should do, if you do not want to modify the initial `myArray` (pure function)

```js
// Initialization
myArray = [
  {SKU: "Hoo12", Name: "ACyrlic watch",OrderNo:"26423764233456"},
  {SKU: "S0002", Name: "Princes Geometry",OrderNo:"122324234234"},
  {SKU: "Hoo12", Name: "ACyrlic watch",OrderNo:"122324234234"},
]

OutPut = []

// For each element of the array
myArray.forEach(elem => {
  // find the one that match with SKU and Name
  let found = OutPut.find(o => o.SKU == elem.SKU && o.Name == elem.Name)
  // if it present add the OrderNo
  if (found) {
    found.OrderNo.push(elem.OrderNo)
  }
  // else add the object with OrderNo as an Array
  else {
    OutPut.push({ SKU: elem.SKU, Name: elem.Name, OrderNo: [ elem.OrderNo ] })
  }
})


// Show output
let c = document.createElement('pre');
c.innerText = JSON.stringify(OutPut, null, 2)
document.body.appendChild(c)
```